# AttributeError at /admin/accounts/user/1/change/ 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django, api, model, admin, profile

I am creating an API. When i create a new user, or edit an existing user and save, i get this error
"AttributeError at /admin/accounts/user/1/change/
'User' object has no attribute 'profile"

For clarity, I have a user model and a profile model lied o my User model with a onetoone relationship.

Here is my User model

```
    artist_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, 
        default='artist name', 
        unique=True
        )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
    User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
     related_name="user", 
     default=1
     )
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True, null=True)
record_label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
image = models.FileField()
```

And my signals

```
from .models import User, Profile
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I should also mention that I don't have views for my user and profile yet. But i don't think that should affect the admin area.
So far i have searched online but nothing worked.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Why have the two signal handlers for the same signal? You can combine them into one, move `instance.profile.save()` to the `else` of the first handler

Answer (score 0):

i would advice you not to create a seperate user model, rather use the default User model. note that some of the features you need on your Profile model are actually present in the User model. in User model you have first_name, last_name,email,username, password1 and password2 by default but if you only what to use the User model you specified then follow the steps. so in your profile model the fields you should specify should be as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import User, Profile
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class User(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='artist name', unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True, null=True)
    record_label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        instance.profile.save()
```

I hope this helps and if it does vote up this answer and give response.